# Java: The keyword "this" and Serialization

Tags: java

I have a simple class as shown below.

All what I want to achieve with this class is to make the instance serialized into a byte array, but I keep getting `java.io.NotSerializableException`.

What is wrong with my code?

Is *this* just a pointer to an instance created upon calling the constructor and not the actual instance object?

```
class XXX {
  private String someStr;

  public XXX(String someStr){
    this.someStr = someStr;
  }

  public byte[] toByteArray(){
        byte[] output = null;
        try(ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
        ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(out)) {
            stream.writeObject(this);
            output = out.toByteArray();
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
        return output;
    }

}

XXX aX = new XXX("some string");
aX.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [NotSerializableException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/NotSerializableException.html)

> Thrown when an instance is required to have a Serializable interface. The serialization runtime or the class of the instance can throw this exception. The argument should be the name of the class.

You need to implement **Serializable interface** in you class.

```
class XXX implements Serializable {
 ...
}
```

See the output here [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/h4uRWL)

> [-84, -19, 0, 5, 115, 114, 0, 6, 73, 100, 101, 111, 110, 101, 107, -60, 36, 124, 45, 63, 13, 80, 2, 0, 1, 76, 0, 7, 115, 111, 109, 101, 83, 116, 114, 116, 0, 18, 76, 106, 97, 118, 97, 47, 108, 97, 110, 103, 47, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 59, 120, 112, 116, 0, 11, 115, 111, 109, 101, 32, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103]

Comment: I should have mentioned that the class XXX is a nested non-static class, but anyway what you pointed out got me pointed in the right direction. thanks